# Send FORM Data in JSON format to Web API action without submiting the form

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

I need to preview the content of a form without submitting it. The idea is:

1. Get the form data, e.g, labels, inputs and textarea values;
2. Send the data using AJAX to a URL where I will "prepare" the data;
3. Display the data in a template using (http://www.berriart.com/sidr)

I have a form example:

```
<form method="post">
  <label for="Name">Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" value="John" id="Name">
  <label for="CV">Curriculum Vitae</label>
  <textarea value="I am ..." id="CV" data-parser="markdown">I am  ...</textarea> 
  <label for="Roles">User Roles</label>
  <select id="Roles">
    <option value="1" selected>Admin</option>
    <option value="2">Collaborator</option>
  </select> 
  <label for="Active">Active</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="true" id="Active">
</form>
```

So in this case I need to get the data:

```
Full Name: John (Label text and Input value)
Curriculum Vitae: I am ... (Label text and Input value)
Roles: Admin (Label text and Selected option)
...
```

I want to get a JSON object so I can manipulate it and return to display it in Sidr.

I also need to send the value in data-parser when it exists ...

The textarea, for example, has data-parser="markdown".

How can I get the form data and send it to an ASP.NET Web API action in JSON format?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery to serialize the form, then send to controller:   http://api.jquery.com/serialize/